# Limit of $(2xy)^{xy}$ as $(x,y) \to (0, 2)$

Tags: calculus

Limit of $(2xy)^{xy}$ as $(x,y) \to (0, 2)$

I can't figure this out.  I've tried the substitution $u=xy$ but then I get indeterminate form with the natural logarithm, which doesnt exist in this case

My book says the answer is $L=1$

Answer (score 1):

You have trouble if $xy<0$.
If you stay in the first quadrant, the logarithm is $$xy\log(2xy)=\frac{\log(2xy)}{1/xy}$$
and now you can use L'Hopital

Comment: would this work? ; $u=xy$ so $u→0$ then Limit of $\left( 2u \right)^{u}$ as $u→0$ is $0^{0}=1$

Comment: I don't think we can do $0^0$ because it is in indeterminate form.  Also, @Michael are we just allowed to restrict the domain and change it to $u \to 0^+$